# Why can't I start a thread within a user control constructor?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-controls

First off, I know this is bad practice... this has turned into more of a "NEED TO KNOW" exercise then a best practices exercise at this point.

I have a usercontrol which is initialized from the constructor of the main winform.  In that USerControl, I am trying to start a keep alive thread

```
public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Disposed += Dispose;

        // Start the keep alive Thread
        _keepAliveThread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                    try
                    {
                        _service.Ping();
                        Trace.WriteLine("Ping called on the Service");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Ping failed");
                    }
                }
            });
        _keepAliveThread.Start();
    }
```

Whenever I do this, the dispose does not fire within the designer nor do I get the event.

Simply not starting the thread, the dispose fires.  Again... I know this is bad practice, but trying to figure out why this just doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean 'dispose does not fire within the designer'? How are you checking it without it running? I don't see anything in the `Output` window to suggest it would be disposing from the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
public partial class SillyControl : UserControl
{
    Thread backgroundThread;
    Service service = new Service();

    public SillyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Disposed += delegate { Trace.WriteLine("I been disposed!"); };

        backgroundThread = new Thread(argument =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Background ping thread has started.");

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                try
                {
                    service.Ping();
                    Trace.WriteLine("Ping!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Ping failed: {0}", ex.Message)); 
                }
            }
        });

        backgroundThread.IsBackground = true; // <- Important! You don't want this thread to keep the application open.
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work either.  Actually, the syntax was incorrect as well I believe.  The _service is expecting to be an int for the Thread constructor.

Comment: @AndySousa I've edited the syntax, looking into it further now that I have VS open.

Comment: I just updated it as you did... testing now.  The dispose still does not get call and the application doesn't exit.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've changed my answer entirely as I think I see what the problem is. It is important to set `Thread.IsBackground` to `true`. If you don't, the application will remain open/running until all non-background threads are killed. In most cases, the UI (main thread) should be the only non-background thread.

Comment: that did it... thanks.  I would think IsBackground=true would be the default action.

Comment: @AndySousa It is sort of a gotcha. Fortunately there are so many better alternatives to creating an actual `Thread` object now that there is very little reason to. `BackgroundWorker`, `Begin/End` async methods, and the `Task` library are all far better alternatives depending on which .NET version you are using.