# C# Win-Forms User Control background task execution delay

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

I have C# Windows Forms application which consists of Form and a User Control.

I try to run code in background thread inside a User Control added to Form, here's code I use inside User Control:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowNotification("Invoke", $"Start Invoke { DateTime.Now}");
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ShowNotification("Run", $"Start Run { DateTime.Now}");
    });
}

private void ShowNotification(string title, string message, ToolTipIcon icon = ToolTipIcon.Info)
{
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20, title, message, icon);
}
```

When running this project in Release mode no problems with execution. However, when running this project in Debug mode the code inside Task.Run is executed after 1.5 minutes of pressing the button which means that second notification is shown after 1.5 minutes of the first one.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

After doing more search about this issue I found this question which was helpful to do a workaround on the problem:

[Why can't I start a thread within a user control constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269725/why-cant-i-start-a-thread-within-a-user-control-constructor)

replacing:

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ShowNotification("Run", $"Start Run { DateTime.Now}");
    });
```

with:

```
 var notificationThread =
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    ShowNotification("Run", $"Start Run {DateTime.Now}");
                })
                { IsBackground = true};

            notificationThread.Start();
```

Have solved the problem.

Comment: You can't interact with a UI element from a non-UI thread. I suspect your problem is because of that. How does it behave when you don't use the `Task`?

Comment: When I don't use Task it works without problems. even in my way it works on Release mode. the issue appears only on Debug mode.

Comment: You should use the `Invoke` answer below with tasks and see if that works.

Comment: I already commented on the answer that is not working!!

Comment: Well that's interesting. I'm looking forward to seeing the actual answer to this question too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke the thread.

```
private void ShowNotification(string title, string message, ToolTipIcon icon = ToolTipIcon.Info)
{
    MethodInvoker Invoker = new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20, title, message, icon);
    });

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(Invoker);
    }
    else
    {
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20, title, message, icon);
    }      
}
```

Comment: Don't repeat code. Either call `ShowNotification` in the `this.Invoke` call or use the `Invoker` delegate on both sides of the `if`. The preference would be the former over the latter.

Comment: Also, an explanation would be appropriate.

Comment: using Invoke is not solving the problem, I tried it before.

My problems is not with showing notification on button press, this is a simplified code just to explain the issue.

The real issue here is as explain with Title, executing code in background task in user control.